# Angular Dialog Button doesn't respond to data binding with boolean

Tags: angular, binding, dialog, boolean

So, my problem is simple but I couldn't manage to solve it and nor I found any help on internet.

I have an Angular component with 2 dialogs. I have a button bound to a bool in my typescript, as you can see here:

```js
export class ModalDB {
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }
  enabledState: boolean = true;

  changeStates(){
    // let content = document.getElementById('db-pdf-body-scroll')
    // if (content.scrollTop+5 >= (content.scrollHeight - content.offsetHeight)) {
    //        console.log(this.enabledState)
    // } 
    this.enabledState = false; 
    console.log(this.enabledState)
  }

  toggleButton(){
    this.enabledState = false;
  }

  ngOnInit():void{
    console.log(this.enabledState)

    document.getElementById("db-pdf-body-scroll").addEventListener(
      'scroll',
      function(event){
        if (this.scrollTop+5 >= (this.scrollHeight - this.offsetHeight)) {
          ModalDB.prototype.changeStates();          
        } 
      },
      true // Capture event
  );
  }
  
 

  closeModalDB(){
    console.log("User didnt agree db")

    this.dialog.closeAll();
  }

  agreeDB(){
    console.log("User agreed db")
    this.dialog.closeAll();
  }
}
```

Here I have the HTML for this:

```html
<div mat-dialog-actions align="end">
    <button id="acceptDB" mat-raised-button color="primary" [attr.disabled]="enabledState" (click)="agreeDB()">Sunt de acord</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="closeModalDB()">Nu sunt de acord</button>
</div>
```

When I try to log the variable `enabledState` it changes. So my function works. But for some reason the DOM won't change.

As much as I tried to fix this I couldn't. I checked the hooks, even tried to split the function in more individual components but nothing solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably it's because you're passing a callback as a plain JS function and trying to access a class member variable within it. The scope of `this` is such cases is confined to within the callback block. Instead you could define the callback as an arrow function.

```js
ngOnInit():void{
  console.log(this.enabledState)
  document.getElementById("db-pdf-body-scroll").addEventListener(
    'scroll',
    (event) => {              // <-- arrow function
      if (this.scrollTop+5 >= (this.scrollHeight - this.offsetHeight)) {
        this.changeStates();  // <-- call `this.changeState()` here
      } 
    },
    true // Capture event
  );
}
```

Moreover using `document` to access elements is inelegant in Angular since it'll crawl the entire DOM instead of only the specific component. Instead you could use Angular template reference variable with RxJS `fromEvent` to listen to events.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Michael, and also, for the people having the same problem as I did, I suggest you to replace

```
[attr.disabled]
```

with

```
 [disabled]
```

And the finall code should be this:
HTML:

```
<div mat-dialog-actions align="end">
    <button id="acceptDB" mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="enabledState" (click)="agreeDB()">Sunt de acord</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="closeModalDB()">Nu sunt de acord</button>
</div>
```

COMPONENT

```
  ngOnInit():void{

    let content = document.getElementById('db-pdf-body-scroll')
    console.log(this.enabledState)
    document.getElementById("db-pdf-body-scroll").addEventListener(
      'scroll',
      (event) => {              // <-- arrow function
        if (content.scrollTop+5 >= (content.scrollHeight - content.offsetHeight)) {
          this.changeStates();  // <-- call `this.changeState()` here
        } 
      },
      true // Capture event
    );
  }
```

Thanks again!